# catch php commands while executing

Tags: php

Are there any methods to catch the php commands instead of executing them?
There's a backdoor which is encoded in my server, I was able to get declared classes and methods names, of the backdoor, but I need to find out the real code.

Comment: what is meant by `catch php commands`?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer instead of returning the result of echo "hello world"; you get the echo "hello world"; itself

Comment: On linux, you could use a recursive grep to look for the class or method names rather than executing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 things.

**1.** Use a profiler tool.

**2.** In your own code define a class with the same name. Then when the backdoor class is loaded, it will give a fatal error ('class name already defined') and tell you where the other class resides. Do enable stacktraces in case the backdoor is obfuscated/eval'd/remote included.

Comment: Thank you, I will try both of your suggestions